# Magento - Catalog URL Rewrites -> Processing

Tags: php, magento, url, indexing, url-rewriting

i have a problem with indexing catalog url rewrites. it's stuck on PROCESSING. i truncate `core_url_rewrite` table, and delete files from `var/locks` and nothing. when i try to reindex it on backend it load page with loop and nothing.
i tried to reindex it with ssh, but every time i become only help file in response:

```
[~/public_html/shell]# php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url

Content-type: text/html

Usage:  php -f indexer.php -- [options]

  --status <indexer>            Show Indexer(s) Status

  --mode <indexer>              Show Indexer(s) Index Mode

  --mode-realtime <indexer>     Set index mode type "Update on Save"

  --mode-manual <indexer>       Set index mode type "Manual Update"

  --reindex <indexer>           Reindex Data

  info                          Show allowed indexers

  reindexall                    Reindex Data by all indexers

  help                          This help


  <indexer>     Comma separated indexer codes or value "all" for all indexers
```

Comment: What if you update the status to "pending" for catalog_url in the table index_process?

Comment: on the backend after few seconds i become info: "Something went wrong with the site caching! Please try refreshing this page, that should fix the issue." and when i go back to index managment there is still "processing"

Comment: one thing what i see: in the table core_url rewrite rows are still adding - about 100 rows per 5minutes, so indexing is working. should it take so much time? i have about 4300 products and 7 store views.

Comment: The core URL rewrites may take a long time to reindex, depending upon your server resources. Expect the number of rewrites to be greater than or equal to the following equation: (number of stores) * (number of products + number of categories + (number of products * number of categories)). In this case you would have at least tens of thousands of URL rewrites, which, given the heavily indexed nature of the core_url_rewrite table, could take a while to insert.

Comment: indexind end in database with 504 rows in core_url_rewrite table ;/ in backend is still Processing. i made some test, i turn reindexing process on and after 30secs refresh table core_url_rewrite and there was about 22 000 rows, after next 10secs there was about 30 000, next 10secs about 35 000 rows... and after about one minute from start reindexing process there is again 504 rows.